# Running executable files using Haskell

Tags: shell, haskell, command-line-arguments, executable

Say there's a C++ code that I've compiled into an executable using:

```
g++ test.cpp -o testcpp
```

I can run this using Terminal (I'm using OS X), and provide an input file for processing inside the C++ program, like:

```
./testcpp < input.txt
```

I was wondering if doing this is possible, from *within* Haskell. I have heard about the `readProcess` function in `System.Process` module. But that only allows for running system shell commands.

Doing this:

```
out <- readProcess "testcpp" [] "test.in"
```

or:

```
out <- readProcess "testcpp < test.in" [] ""
```

or:

```
out <- readProcess "./testcpp < test.in" [] ""
```

throws out this error (or something very similar depending on which one of the above I use):

```
testcpp: readProcess: runInteractiveProcess: exec: does not exist (No such file or directory)
```

So my question is, whether doing this is possible from Haskell. If so, how and which modules/functions should I use? Thanks.

**EDIT**

Ok, so as David suggested, I removed the input arguments and tried running it. Doing this worked:

```
out <- readProcess "./testcpp" [] ""
```

But I'm still stuck with providing the input.

Comment: In the first part, you have an executable named `test` and in the second part you're trying to run an executable named `testcpp`. Is this correct? Also I think you need to read the contents of `test.in` and then pass that string as the last argument, rather than giving the file name.

Comment: @DavidYoung Yes, I just provided general examples of what I was trying to do. But as it appears to be confusing, I edited it. As for the second part of your comment, didn't quite get you. AFAIK, the problem is with running the exec file itself, and not with providing the input arguments.

Comment: you can always create a file with a shell script, and run *it*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [documentation for `readProcess`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/process-1.2.3.0/docs/System-Process.html#v:readProcess) says:

```
readProcess
  :: FilePath   Filename of the executable (see RawCommand for details)
  -> [String]   any arguments
  -> String     standard input
  -> IO String  stdout
```

When it's asking for `standard input` it's not asking for a file to read the input from, but the actual contents of standard input for the file.

So you'll need to use [`readFile`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:readFile) or the like to get the contents of `test.in`:

```
input <- readFile "test.in"
out <- readProcess "./testcpp" [] input
```